# How to prove $\langle ux-ty,(t^2-1)x-uy\rangle\subseteq\mathbb R[t,u,x,y]/\langle u^2-t^3+t\rangle$ is not a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $C = \mathbb R[t,u]/(u^2 −t^3 + t) $. Consider $\mathrm{Spec}_R(C[x,y])$. 
>   I am proving the subscheme $Z_T$ of $\mathrm{Spec}_R(C[x,y])$, where $T=\langle ux-ty,(t^2-1)x-uy\rangle$ is not a principal $C$-line.

I proved that once I know that $\langle ux-ty,(t^2-1)x-uy\rangle$ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb R[t,u,x,y]/\langle u^2-t^3+t\rangle$ then it is done. I supposed it is principal and want a contradiction. But I have stuck on it for some time without progress.

Note that for proving that $Z_T$ is not a principal $C$-line it suffices to prove that $ ux-ty,(t^2-1)x-uy $ has no common divisor in the form $fx-gy$. I have also tried this.

Am I on the right track? How can I show the ideal here is not principal (or at least not in the form $\langle fx-gy\rangle$ for any $f,g\in C$)?

Comment: Hints. First of all, if your ideal is principal then it must be generated by an element of the form $fx-gy$ with $f,g\in C$. Second, if this happens then notice that $u=fa$ and $v=ga$ for some $a\in C$. But $u,v$ are irreducible in $C$ (why?) and then $a$ is associate with $1$, so the generator must be $uX-vY$. This leads to $u/v\in C$, a contradiction.

Comment: @user26857 In my attempt yesterday I tried to prove that $u,v$ are irreducible... But I have not reach a proof. So could you please explain this a bit?

Comment: I think once I prove that $u,t$ are irreducible than it would be nearly solved, since I have deduced if the line is principal then $\langle u,t\rangle=\langle p\rangle$ for some $p\in C$.

Comment: Write the elements of $C$ as $a(t)+b(t)u$. Then from $u=[a(t)+b(t)u][c(t)+d(t)u]$ you get $a(t)c(t)+b(t)d(t)(t^3-t)+[a(t)d(t)+c(t)b(t)-1]u\in(u^2-t^3+t)$ and this is possible (by a degree argument) iff $a(t)c(t)+b(t)d(t)(t^3-t)=0$ and $a(t)d(t)+c(t)b(t)-1=0$. From here you must reach to a contradiction. Similarly for $t$.

Comment: @user26857 Sorry I still cannot get it... Where is the contradiction?